# How to list all source files (*.c, *.cpp, *.h)

Tags: find, grep, regex

I'd like to find source files (*.c, *.cpp, *.h) that contain  in Linux/MinGW/Cygwin, and recursively in all sub directories.

My basic idea is using `find` and `grep`. However, building a regular expression that can check given file name is either *.c, *.cpp, or *.h isn't easy. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 18):

This should work:

```
find Linux/MinGW/Cygwin -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
find . -regex '.*/.*\.\(c\|cpp\|h\)$'
```

Comment: What does the `$` at the end of the command do?

Comment: @Ali: It anchors the regex to the end of the line (it prevents finding files named `foo.cpp.old` for example).

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
find . -regex '.*\.\(c\|cpp\|h\)$' -print
```

Comment: In my macbook, the script without a `-E` can't find anything.  you might need add a -E (as extended) to make it more portable, just like `find -E . -regex '.*\.(c|h|cpp)' -print`.       ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty, and avoids directory names:

```
find . -type f -name *.[c\|h]
```

Comment: There are three problems with this command: 1. It won't find `*.cpp` files. 2. It will find `*.|` files. 3. The glob will expand if there are matching files in the current directory. Quoting prevents that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a slightly simpler regex:

```sh
find . -type f -regex ".*\.[ch]\(pp\)?$"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a mac pro which also works in bash. But every time I type in the command line:

```
find -name
```

it says illegal option. So I just simplified it as:

```
find *.c *.cpp *.h
```

and found it really worked!

Comment: I don't think that does what you think. I think the shell is expanding the `*` before being passed to `find`. What you end up with is something like `find file1.c file1.h file2.c`, etc. , and only for files in the current directory, not any sub-directories. The shell only expands `*` to the names of files in the current directory. You can just use `ls` for that.

Answer (score 0):

On my mac book pro {macOS Catalina}, the following did the trick:

```
find . | grep ".*/.*\.\(c\|cpp\|h\)$"
```